# Automatically setting a date for an activity being added by a sequence

Tags: civicase, activities

I am attempting to set up a timeline for a set of case types. I made a sequence for a few activities. However, the scheduled date automatically sets to the current day. How do I get it so that when an activity is added due to a sequence, its date is set based off an offset value?

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: @Aiden 4.7.18 currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the issue that I am having. It turns out there is a bug in version 4.7.18 that is fixed in 4.7.20. So I will just need to wait for the release version.

Answer (score 1):

Sequences are different than timelines and don't have offsets. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/case-management/set-up/#define-case-types and go down to step 5.

> A Sequence defines the order in which a set of defined activities should occur, but unlike the timeline it includes no information about time intervals between activities.

For timelines use the reference and offset fields.

> In a Timeline you control the scheduling of each activity in your timeline relative to the date the case is opened, or relative to another activity in the case, using the 'Reference' and 'Offset' fields.

Comment: Well my other issue is that Civicrm won't let me set a reference. When I click on the drop down box no activities show up.

Comment: How close is it to a fresh install? Are you able to reproduce that problem on the public demo (http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/)?

Comment: I went to the public demo and I do not see the same result. Could it be a version issue. The public demo is running 4.7.21, and I am running 4.7.18.  edit: also, I am using bitnami stack to install drupal, civicrm, and my WAMP stack.

Comment: If you go to administer - customize data and screens - activity types, do you see any listed for the CiviCase component? Maybe that stack doesn't install the stock case config by default? Were there any case types/timelines already present after install?